# JQuery Select one of multiple img in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

I'm new to JQuery and stuck on a simple problem. I wanted to take the markup below, and create a script that places a larger version of the mouse'd over img (one of the five from div) into p, "big". The one in "big" will match the last mouseover target, and will function as a link- just the same as the smaller version.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
            <title>Image Links</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p id = "big">

            </p>
            <div id = "links">
                <a href = "http://www. .com/"><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" .png" width = "100" height = "150" onmouseover="enlargeCopy();">
                <a href = "https://www. .com "><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" " width = "200" height = "100">
                <a href = "https://www. .com/"><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" .png" width = "100" height = "100">
                <a href = "http://www. .com/"><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" .png" width = "100" height = "100">
                <a href = "https://www. .com/"><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" .png" width = "100" height = "100">
            </div>
            <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
            <script src = "Test 3.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

This is the js script I've attempted to use ><. The closest I've come to success is getting [object Object] to appear multiple times (instead of the intended larger image).

```
//intended to increase the size of imgs in div, and place the larger image at the top of the document

var enlargeCopy = function () {

    var x = $(".links").children("img").css("width", "*=2");
    var x = $(".links").children("img").css("height", "*=2");

    document.getElementById("big").appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
};
```

What I am attempting to do- explained more concisely:

-1. is to hover over any one of the five image anchors (in div of the html document)

-2. for the image that is being moused over to appear as a copy at the top of the page (in the currently empty p slot)

-3. for that copy to be twice as wide and twice as long as the moused over target

-4. for the copy to still also function as a link

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: $(".links").children() will return the immediate child elements, in your case <a> elements.

Comment: I'll figure out how to rephrase it- but I needed to copy the image that's being moused over to the top part of the document. The copied image must still retain the qualities of an anchored link, and must be twice as long and wide

Comment: @user3734311, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you corectly you want to clone the image and append it to some element on mouseover, right? Maybe you can use jQuery's clone method:

```js
$('#links a').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#big');
  var originalWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
  var originalHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  $('#big, #big img').css({'width': originalWidth * 2 + 'px', 'height': originalHeight * 2 + 'px'});
});
```

Also, you should close your anchor tags like this `</a>`.

I've also made you a [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/25xd7ojn/).

Comment: Not quite. Running it through the debugger and not getting anything. Can't get it to function either. I am assuming that it's still necessary to leave the "onmouseover" property on the a href object, right?

Comment: Yes. Remove the onmouseover and include jQuery library too, and it will work. I think this is a cleaner and better solution.

Comment: Very much appreciated, it works like a charm- just need to overwrite old moused overs with new ones now- but that doesn't seem too difficult. Thanks a million :D

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it clones the link too. Because you said you wanted it clickable. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

-First add same name to the five `<a>` you are going to use. For example:

```
<a name="exampleLink" href = "http://www. .com/"><img id = " " border = "0" alt = " " src=" .png" width = "100" height = "150" >
```

-Then add an evenlistener to this name:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
   $('a[name=exampleLink]').mouseover(function() {
         $(this).clone().appendTo($('#big').empty());
   });
});
```

Now you only need do the img biggest as you say, but i havn't time enougth, sure someone can edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
  <img src="" id="big" style="display: none;"> <!-- empty hidden image -->
</p>
<div id="links">
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img border="0" alt="1" src="https://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/content/books/learning-jquery-4th-ed.jpg" width="100" height="150" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img border="0" alt="2" src="https://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/content/books/jquery-in-action.jpg" width="200" height="100" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img border="0" alt="3" src="https://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/content/books/jquery-succinctly.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img border="0" alt="4" src="https://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/jq-global-nav.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
</div>


  $('#links a').mouseover(function(){
    var $el = $(this).children('img');
    $('#big')
      .attr('src', $el.attr('src'))
      .width($el[0].naturalWidth * 2)
      .height($el[0].naturalHeight * 2)
      .show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your selector to `$("#links")`  instead of `$(".links")`
   **Your modified function is following.**
   `var enlargeCopy = function () {
    var x = $("#links").children("img").css("width", "*=2");
    var x = $("#links").children("img").css("height", "*=2");
    document.getElementById("big").appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
    };`